# Find out both chat participants in ms teams tab (javascript)

Tags: javascript, microsoft-teams

Our applications has relationships between users, and we want to show the relationships in MS teams tabs.

Imagine there's a chat between User A and User B in msteams.
User A is currently logged in to ms teams, and adds our app's tab to the chat.

In the tab, we want to show relationship between User A and User B (if it exists). Therefore we need to somehow identify User B (email would be the best).

Through MS teams SDK I can find out chat ID, but not id of User B.
I found Graph API route to get members via chat ID: [List conversationMembers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmember-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=javascript)

Unfortunately, it's in beta. If I understand correctly, it means I cannot use it for production.

Is there other way to find out information (id, email) of User B?

Here is how context looks for tabs (values changed). 
It's the same both for configuration page and tab itself.

```
{
  "appSessionId": "0db8663f-35cd-4231-ba3a-a3089b151f8",
  "chatId": "19:15d9c400-6c59-4379-914e-d6d22d1597aa_a883b685-0733-46da-b102-ce7974668cf@unq.gbl.spaces",
  "entityId": "",
  "hostClientType": "desktop",
  "isFullScreen": false,
  "jsonTabUrl": "microsoft-teams-json-tab.azurewebsites.net",
  "locale": "en-us",
  "loginHint": "u1.dabra@outlook.com",
  "ringId": "general",
  "sessionId": "882ef0d4-e222-5ec4-79d9-6911debf550",
  "subEntityId": "",
  "teamSiteDomain": "dabra.sharepoint.com",
  "teamSitePath": "",
  "teamSiteUrl": "",
  "tenantSKU": "free",
  "theme": "default",
  "tid": "9703245a-7156-4221-b92d-ec339ddf183",
  "upn": "myemail@outlook.com",
  "userLicenseType": "Unknown",
  "userObjectId": "a883b685-0733-46da-b102-ce797466c7",
  "userPrincipalName": "admin@Dabra.onmicrosoft.com"
}
```

**Upd:**
I was not able to solve my problem yet, but I've found way to get chat users inside the bot when installing tab. Maybe this code will be useful to someone.

Response is the list of chat users we are looking for.

```
this.onTeamsMembersAddedEvent(async (teamMembersAdded, teamInfo, turnContext, next) => {
    const connector = turnContext.adapter.createConnectorClient(turnContext.activity.serviceUrl);
    const conversationId = turnContext.activity.conversation.id;
    const response = await connector.conversations.getConversationMembers(conversationId);
// Response is the list of users in chat
console.log(response);
      await next();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to get all the members of the current conversation using the TurnContext.Conversation.GetConversationMembersAsync method, if you're using a Bot, written in C# (I'm sure there's an equivalent for a Bot in Node.js). What this means is that, if you add a Bot to your application as well as the existing Tab, you can query for the conversation members when the Bot is added to the group chat. When the Bot *is* added to the conversation, it receive a OnMembersAddedAsync event, where you could do the "GetConversationMembersAsync" call, something like this:

```
protected override Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

            List<ChannelAccount> teamMembers = (await turnContext.TurnState.Get<IConnectorClient>().Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(
                turnContext.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>().Team.Id).ConfigureAwait(false)).ToList();

            List<MicrosoftTeamUser> teamsUsers = new List<MicrosoftTeamsUser>();
            foreach (var item in teamMembers)
            {
                var teamsUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MicrosoftTeamUser>(item.Properties.ToString());
                teamsUser.Id = item.Id;
                teamsUsers.Add(teamsUser);
            }
}
```

You'll need a definition for MicrosoftTeamsUser, as follows:

```
public class MicrosoftTeamsUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string ObjectId { get; set; }

    public string GivenName { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string UserPrincipalName { get; set; }

    public string TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I found JS equivalent after some research and was able get both chat participants.
The problem is I cannot use this when installing a tab.

I can, of course, get users related to chat Id to our database and then query from tab. But it's not guaranteed that data will be saved at the time user clicks save button, so this method cannot be fully relied on.

I cannot accept the answer as it does not fully solve my problem, but it is useful to know anyway. So thank you for the answer!

Comment: yes, I see your point, it won't enable you to get the channel members 100% at the exact point in time from your tab. I have another possible option though - depending on what your tab does, you might be able to launch a Task Module (basically a Teams popup window), and a Task Module has the ability to call back into it's related Bot when it's task is complete. This would be useful because "GetConversationMembersAsync" can be called *any* time, not just from OnMembersAddedAsync. You'd basically be calling this on demand to do a refresh. I haven't tried this so so ymmv!

Comment: By the way,  if the answer was at least partially useful, please consider at least an "upvote" instead of a "mark as answer" :-)